# What methods exist to handle non politically correct recommendations?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

Every now and then we hear about another ML-based recommendation system that suggested a politically offensive result to users. What methods are currently in use to prevent such cases in modern recommendation systems?

Comment: This has nothing to do with recommendation systems, it's about filtering out offensive text. In general this is regular text classification, but it's always difficult because offensiveness is a moving target.

Comment: I only know this to be a topic of discussion in Natural Language Processing. Can you provide examples or a reference where this is discussed with regards to recommendations?

Comment: For example: https://money.cnn.com/2006/01/06/news/companies/walmart_dvd/?cnn=yes

Answer (score 1):

Solutions require creating a list of politically offensive terms. Assuming there is a list of politically offensive terms, there are three primary methods:

1. Filter the data. Remove offensive terms from the training data.
2. Constrain the optimization. Do not allow solutions that include the terms.
3. Filter the output. Create ranked results and present the first result that does not have the terms.

Given that the definition of politically offensive changes based the person, the context, and implied meaning, it will be very difficult to prevent offending someone at sometime.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the literature about detecting offensiveness is always about detecting offensive content (in text, images, audio...).
However based on the [linked article in the comment](https://money.cnn.com/2006/01/06/news/companies/walmart_dvd/?cnn=yes) this type of problem is not about the content, it's the association of item X with item Y which is considered offensive even though neither X or Y are offensive on their own.

This is a very difficult problem because there's no information that the system can use as a clue that the association is offensive. So as far as I'm aware it's pretty much impossible to prevent this based on the content itself, and I doubt that even modern recommender systems can.

But this doesn't mean that nothing can be done. In a case like this, I would investigate carefully how the recommender reached these associations based on the data. I suspect that this kind of pattern was maliciously introduced either by some of the employees working on the system or even some users: some group of users may notice how their "likes" or ratings modify the recommendations of the system and coordinate to trick the system (similarly to something like [Google bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_bombing)). Detecting anomalous behaviour in the ratings of a group of users should be more easily detectable, but that's not directly part of the recommender system itself. It's possible that major companies which rely on a recommendation system have such monitoring in place.